# ionic2 page navigation doesn't active the corresponding tab

Tags: angular, ionic2

**HTML**

```html
<button ion-button block (click)="goto()">Search</button>
```

**Typescript**

```typescript
goto() {        
      this.navCtrl.push(ListingsPage, {'area':this.area}); 
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to go directly to a Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562356/how-to-go-directly-to-a-tab/44573545#44573545)

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562356/how-to-go-directly-to-a-tab/44573545#44573545)

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras , I have tried with your example given in pluker it works fine and selects tab where do we are, but it is not showing the real content of the second tabs page. Please do look at this.

Comment: There was an error when the page was being set, because the content was being hidden behind the navbar for some reason. I've fixed the plunker, so you can take a look at it again now :)

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras still it is not working for me , Even I have used you code model

Comment: What do you mean by that? The plunker works properly as I can see, or is there something wrong on that plunker?

Comment: yeah , project in the plunker is working fine but I"m trying the same code is not working

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you in that case, you must be missing something because if it works in the plunker, should work just like that on your end...