# Ionic 2 - Navigation with Tabs from Menu

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Can you help me to navigate from SideMenu to another page with saving Tabs?

My app.html

```
...
<a menuToggle tappable (click)="userPage(1)">User page</a>
...
```

My app.component.ts

```
userPage(user_id) {
  this.nav.push('UserPage', {
     userId : user_id,
  }) ;
}
```

My tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage {

    tab1Root = 'ProjectsPage';
    tab2Root = 'ContractorsPage';
    tab3Root = 'SuppliersPage';
    tab4Root = 'VacanciesPage';
    tab5Root = 'BeInTrendPage';
    tab6Root = 'UserPage';

    constructor() { }

}
```

When i go to User page from userPage() function, Tabs not displaying on page.

Comment: In which component is the `userPage(...)` method defined? Is inside of any of the other tabs?

Comment: component `UserPage` defined in Tabs component `tab6Root = 'UserPage';`

Comment: I was asking about the method `userPage(...)`, not the component

Comment: in app.component.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/):

> You can also switch tabs from a child component by calling `select()` on
>   the parent view using the `NavController` instance. For example,
>   assuming you have a `TabsPage` component, you could call the following
>   from any of the child components to switch to `TabsRoot3`:
>
> ```
> switchTabs() {
>   this.navCtrl.parent.select(2);
> }
> ```

So one way to do it, would be to use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/). The idea would be to publish an event when the option from the side menu is selected, and subscribe to that event in the `UserPage`, and select that tab as the active one.

So, in the `userPage` method from the `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

userPage(user_id) {
  this.events.publish('user:selected', user_id);
}
```

And then in the `UserPage` tab:

```
import { Events, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  this.events.subscribe('user:selected', (user_id) => {
    // First select this tab if any other tab was selected
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(5); // It's the 6th tab, so its index is 5

    // Now you can load the data using the user_id, and show it in the view
    // ...
  });

}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, it may happen that if the tabs has not been created yet, nothing will happen (since we're subscribing to the event in the constructor).

So instead of subscribing to that event on the `UserPage` tab, let's try with the `TabsPage` (the one that contains all the child tabs). Since we're going to use the parent tab, we'd need a new shared service to store the selected *user_id*. So, create a new shared service, like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

 @Injectable()
 export class ParamService {

  public selectedUser: any;

  constructor(){ }
}
```

Please also add it to the providers array of your `NgModule` (from your `app.module.ts` file).

So, in the `userPage` method from the `app.component.ts` file, now we save the user id using the share service before publishing the event:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events, public paramService: ParamService) {}

userPage(user_id) {
  this.paramService.selectedUser = user_id;
  this.events.publish('user:selected');
}
```

Remove the code of the `UserPage` tab, and add this to the `TabsPage`:

```
import { ViewChild, ... } from '@angular/core';
import { Events, NavController, ... } from 'ionic-angular';

@ViewChild('tabs') tabRef: Tabs;

constructor(public events: Events, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  this.events.subscribe('user:selected', () => {
    // First select the proper tab if any other tab was selected
    this.tabRef.select(5);
  });

}
```

And last but not least, in the `UserPage` tab, use the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook to get the selected `user_id` from the `paramService`:

```
public userToShow: any;

constructor(public paramService: ParamService) {}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.userToShow = this.paramService.selectedUser;
}
```

Comment: I received the error  `No provider for NavController`

Comment: Don't import the `NavController ` in the `app.component.ts` file, just in the `UserPage` tab.

Comment: Did as you wrote, but now nothing happens when the method is called. There are no errors.
Maybe because I'm using Ionic 3.

But then i go to User Page from tabs and then open from Side Menu it is works.

Comment: Hmm... Seems to be related to the tab not being created until you navigate to it manually. I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks work fine. There was one more question - is it possible open `AnyPage` from `app.component.ts` and show `Tabs`?

If i `this.nav.push('AnyPage')` `Tabs` not showing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you mean something like app.component -> AnyPage -> TabsPage (showing a particular tab) you can take a look at **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562356/how-to-go-directly-to-a-tab/44573545#44573545)**

Comment: A little bit wrong.
From the component `app.component.ts` need to go to `AnyPage` and show on this page `Tabs`